# What is the Get Out procedure called?

Tags: get-out

In the 2017 film Get Out, the Armitage family

> has developed a partial brain transplantation process.

There is a name for this procedure in the film that I think has two words and begins with "C". What is it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The procedure was referred to as **The Coagula**.

Comment: Ah yes, I guess I thought it was multiple words because of the use of the phrase "Behold the Coagula."

Comment: Ah.... thought OP was looking for an actual medical procedure name.